# How to map an special string to a dict in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string like:

```
a_1 = 'A=1,B=3,C=3'
```

I want to map this string to a `dict` to look like:

```
d_1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
```

How should I do this? I am using:

```
dict(a_1)
```

but this returns an error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split()` plus a comprehension to do this:

```
d_1 = dict(pair.split("=") for pair in a_1.split(","))
```

Comment: +1 actually it's "almost perfect" cause your map creates `{'A':'1',...}` and he wants the vals to be ints: `{'A':1,...}`

Comment: @alfasin,it's fine, because some value in my string is also a "string". :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj what are you talking about - it's written elegantly and works just fine!

Comment: @alfasin I believe it is because the OP has two different characters for a `comma` (if you look closely at the typeface for `a_1`). I am betting Avinash just did a copy paste, and split(',') will not split on the second comma.

Comment: @C.B. I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Answer (score 2):

Coercing to `int`:

```
>>> s = 'A=1,B=3,C=3'
>>> dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in [x.split("=") for x in s.split(",")])
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 3}
```

**Update:** A version that tries to coerce values to `int`:

```
def maybeint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

s = 'A=1,B=3,C=3,D=a'
d = dict((k, maybeint(v)) for k, v in [x.split("=") for x in s.split(",")])
```